# Functions $f:X\to X$ with no fixed points, for $X$ a punctured disk or a sphere.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

$X$ is the punctured closed unit disc $D^2-\{0\}  = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \lt x^2+y^2 \le 1\}$

Is the answer that $f$ maps all $(x,y)$ to $0$ which is not included in the unit disk and so there is no fixed point?

What if $X$ is unit sphere  $S^2 = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ can't map anything to something that does not exist.

For the punctured disk, any rotation about the missing point is either a self map with no fixed points, or it is the identity. This gives you plenty of possibilities.

For the sphere $S^2$, the antipodal map, $f(p)=-p$, has no fixed points.

Comment: Thx u very much! For unit disk case, if I map x,y to something like f(x)=x+1 then there is no fixed point. Is this what u mean? BTW, I am new to this topic, can u provide a logical way to solve problems like these?

Comment: no, the map $x\mapsto x+1$ is not well defined for the punctured disk. Think about rotations, not translations! To solve problems like that it helps to have seen many examples of spaces and functions. Also, try to think about it geometrically. For the punctured disk it's really very intuitive that a rotation about the missing point does the job.